# Memory Error when trying to transform with IncrementalPCA from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, scikit-learn, pca

I used a loop to fit the training-batches in the IncrementalPCA method.

```
inc_pca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=154)

for train_batch in np.array_split(X_train,100):
    inc_pca.partial_fit(train_batch)
```

When trying to transform the data it still gives me a memory error:

```
X_reduced = inc_pca.transform(X_train)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 62.8 MiB for an array with shape (42000, 784) and data type float16
```

I used IncrementalPCA to avoid this error why isn't it able to transform the data?
I thought IncrementalPCA would be used for this specific reason when you can't load all the data into Memory at once.
**Can someone tell me why the transforming doesn't work?**